# I have the probabilty distribution values of X and Y for X,Y= 0, 1, 2. Z=XY how do I find the probability distribution of Z?

Tags: probability

*P(X=0)* = 1/4, *P(X= 1)* = 1/4, *P(X=2)*= 1/2

*P(Y=0)*= 1/2, *P(Y= 1)* = 1/3, *P(Y= 2)* = 1/6

Let Z be the random variable defined by Z = XY

**What is the probability of Z?**

This are the answers i got but multiplying the respective probabilities of X and Y for Z.

*P(Z= 0)* = 1/8, *P(Z= 1)* = 1/12, *P(Z= 2)* = 1/12

Are this correct?

Comment: Those probabilities do not add to $1$.

Comment: For $Z=0$...you are only considering the case $X=0=Y$. What about $X=0, Y=1$?  or $X=2, Y=0$?  or...

Comment: The calculations, once corrected, will be right only if we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*. (By the way, it is possible for $XY$ to be $4$.).

Comment: @lulu Yeah knew it was wrong when the total wasn't one

Comment: What would the correct calculation be assuming X and Y are independent?

Comment: For $Z=0$, say, there are $5$ cases to consider.  Namely $(X,Y)=(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,0)$.  $P(Z=0)$ is then just the sum of the probabilities of these cases.  That only leaves $4$ more cases for $(X,Y)$!

Comment: so if z=0 is that what would Z=1 and z=2 be?

Comment: okay I think I get it P(z=0) = 9/16, P(z=1) = 1/12, P(z=2) = 5/24, P(z=4) =1/12? but they total upto 15/16. It should be 1. Am I missing something? Z cannot be 3 as far as i can tell

Comment: P(z=0) =5/8 not 9/16, it was a mistake on my part

Comment: @SAR That's right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$P(Z=0)=P(X=0 \cap Y=0 )+P(X=0 \cap Y=1 )+P(X=1 \cap Y=0 )+P(X=2 \cap Y=0 )+P(X=0 \cap Y=2 )$

$=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{6}$

The other results are right.